# C# Searching between two text box date

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime

I want to search between two date in Ms access database using c#
Indeed to take the two date from two text box and by parameter instead of write direct date inside program
Itrayed :

```
convert(datetime,date,103) between convert(datetime,date1,103) and convert(datetime,date2,103)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have a look at [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
convert(datetime,date,103) between #01.04.2013# and #15.04.2013#
```